# Can Owin also handle responses in its pipeline

Tags: c#, architecture, owin

As I understand Owin now it is a pipeline of modules you can define that handles incoming requests. Any module can return a response or pass the request to the next module. So that makes it very easy to add logging or authentication or whatnot, very cool.

But what if I would like to log responses? Can you create a module that runs for every response, irrespective of where the response came from in the pipeline? If it is possible, can you provide an example or link, I can't seem to find this scenario on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn out it is quite simple and logical, [This blogpost](http://ritzlgrmft.blogspot.nl/2013/06/owin-with-static-files-exception.html) shows an example on how to time the request. Since a module either passes the request on to the next module or RETURNS a response it is just a question of registering a module as the first and processing the returnvalue with ContinueWith:

```
public Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
{
    return _next(environment).ContinueWith(result =>
    {
        Logger.LogResult(result);
        return result;
    });
}
```